# Unable to send inputs of function in generalized way

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trynig to send several parameters as a dict in the format() function, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in open_query
KeyError: 'asset_name'
```

Thisis my code:

```
def open_query(query_file,parameters):
    fd = open(query_file, 'r')
    query = fd.read()
    query = query.format(parameters)
    fd.close()
    return query
```

parameters can one of the following:

```
parameters = {'date_':my_date,'instrument':'BTC_ETH'}
```

or

```
parameters = {'asset_name':'BTC_ETH'}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to double star the dictionary, but you also need to give named values to the template string.

As an example,

```
>>> params={"a":1, "foo":"bar"}
>>> "There is {a} {foo}".format(**params)
'There is 1 bar'
```

You could also look at Jinja2/Mako templates, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

As *cricket_007* wrote, you should use ** to unpack you **parameters dict**

```
query.format(**parameters)
```

But it will still fail for your other input

```
parameters = {'date_':my_date,'instrument':'BTC_ETH'}
query = "{assent_name}"
query.format(**parameters)
```

> KeyError: 'assent_name'

You should think about this case and solve it. Maybe using a default dict

```
from collections import defaultdict 
paramerters = defaultdict(lambda : "N/A")
print("{assent_name}".format_map(paramerters))
```